# How can I automate a drag and drop using VLOOKUP on VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, automation, vlookup

I am trying to write a VBA macro for dragging and dropping a VLOOKUP function so that each row can correspond to the cell being referenced within that row in the VLOOKUP function. Here is the code I wrote to try and reference the corresponding cell address:

```
Sub ReferToCell()

Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Dim LCSheet As Worksheet
Set LCSheet = WB.Worksheets("Livemap Current")

LCROw2 = LCSheet.Cells(LCSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Get new last row of Current
LCSheet.Range(LCSheet.Cells(3, 8), LCSheet.Cells(LCROw2, 8)) = "=IF(ISBLANK(F" & x & "), 99, VLOOKUP(F" & x & ",'Permit Tracker BACKUP'!D:E, 2, 0)) + VLOOKUP(A" & x & ",'Permit Tracker BACKUP'!G:H, 2, 0)" 'not sure what it's supposed to do.
LCSheet.Range(LCSheet.Cells(3, 9), LCSheet.Cells(LCROw2, 9)) = "=IF(AND(F" & x & "<>"""",OR(A" & x & "=""CORE Permits"", A" & x & "=""NED Permits"", A" & x & "=""Anchor & Groundbed Permits"", A" & x & "=""Pole Placement Permits"")), IF(COUNTIFS(E$3:E" & x & ",E" & x & ",F$3:F" & x & ",F" & x & ")>1, """", 1), """")"
LCSheet.Range(LCSheet.Cells(3, 10), LCSheet.Cells(LCROw2, 10)) = "=IFERROR(INDEX('WORK ORDER REPORT'!B:B, MATCH(B3, 'WORK ORDER REPORT'!A:A, 0), 1) & """", """")" 'not sure what it's supposed to do.

LCSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
LCSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("H2:H" & LCROw2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With LCSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what I get in return:
[Column H and J get an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0YjK.png)

Basically, I want to get the Vlookup function to drag and drop automatically without having to type in the function, lock in the ranges, autofill and re-calculating or refreshing the formula. In other words, I want to be able to automate this task on VBA, but I know I am doing something wrong on the code. Any help would be truly appreciated it!! Thank you all in Advance!!

```
 'Declaration of workbook variables
Dim WB _
    , WB2 _
As Workbook
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook 'Live_map_current

'Setting the sheet variables
Dim Nada _
    , CSheet _
    , LCSheet _
    , PSheet _
    , CoreSheet _
    , NedSheet _
    , InSheet _
    , DefSheet _
    , CXSheet _
    , BSheet _
    , AnSheet _
    , PoSheet _
    As Worksheet
    Set Nada = WB.Worksheets("narrow_data")
    Set CoreSheet = WB.Worksheets("CORE Permits")
    Set NedSheet = WB.Worksheets("NED Permits")
    Set InSheet = WB.Worksheets("Inactive Permits")
    Set DefSheet = WB.Worksheets("Carved Permits")
    Set CXSheet = WB.Worksheets("Construction Not Needed")
    Set BSheet = WB.Worksheets("Canceled Permits")
    Set AnSheet = WB.Worksheets("Anchor & Groundbed Permits")
    Set PoSheet = WB.Worksheets("Pole Placement Permits")
    Set LCSheet = WB.Worksheets("Livemap Current")
    
'Define counting variables
Dim ObIDCol _
    , NameCol _
    , NetCol _
    , DY(1 To 5) _
    , PS(1 To 5) _
    , JS _
As Integer

'these variables will be assigned values for populating the Livemap Current page in the latter portion of this script.
Dim DYEAColCount _
    , c _
    , i _
    , n _
    , x _
    , y _
    , FindCol _
    , cRow _
    , NRow _
    , pRow _
    , pCol _
    , cCol _
    , VRow _
    , LCRow _
    , LCROw2 _
    , LCCol _
    , TRow _
    , TOldRow _
    , iLastRow _
    , iLastCol _
As Long
        
'Variables that will filter and format the data on the Livemap current sheet in narrow (long) format.
Dim PageName _
    , Hub _
    , StrFile _
    , UserName _
    , StrFileName _
    , MObIDColLetter _
    , ColLetter _
As String

UserName = Environ$("Username")     'Grabs username for save directory

'Grab Permits_Export file from the desktop
StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\*Permits*")
    StrFileName = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\" & StrFile
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(StrFileName) 'opens the permits files
    WB2.Worksheets("CORE Permits").Columns("A:AR").Copy CoreSheet.Columns("A:AR") 'copies the layer sheets into the new livemap file
    WB2.Worksheets("NED Permits").Columns("A:AR").Copy NedSheet.Columns("A:AR")
    WB2.Worksheets("Inactive Permits").Columns("A:AR").Copy InSheet.Columns("A:AR")
    WB2.Worksheets("Carved Permits").Columns("A:AR").Copy DefSheet.Columns("A:AR")
    WB2.Worksheets("Construction Not Needed").Columns("A:AR").Copy CXSheet.Columns("A:AR")
    WB2.Worksheets("Canceled Permits").Columns("A:AR").Copy BSheet.Columns("A:AR")
    WB2.Worksheets("Anchor & Groundbed Permits").Columns("A:S").Copy AnSheet.Columns("A:S")
    WB2.Worksheets("Pole Placement Permits").Columns("A:S").Copy PoSheet.Columns("A:S")
    WB2.Close False
    StrFile = Dir
    
'Clear Livemap Current sheet on new workbook
Application.StatusBar = "Clear Livemap Current"
LCRow = LCSheet.Cells(LCSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If LCRow > 2 Then
    LCSheet.Range(LCSheet.Cells(3, 1), LCSheet.Cells(LCRow, 9)).ClearContents
    Else: End If

'Set PageName (attribute for pulling the column variables from each layer page--list for compiling and filtering data
LCCol = LCSheet.Cells(1, LCSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Get count of Pages (i.e. attributes)
For c = 1 To LCCol
    PageName = LCSheet.Cells(1, c) 'list of names to grab are in "Livemap Current" sheet, row 1 (hidden)
    Set CSheet = WB.Worksheets(PageName) 'Permit layer data sheets
    Application.StatusBar = PageName

cRow = CSheet.Cells(CSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row of data sheet
cCol = CSheet.Cells(1, CSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Get last col of data sheet

For i = 1 To cCol
    'name
    If CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "OBJECTID" Then
        ObIDCol = i
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "HUB NAME" Then
        NameCol = i
        'Network Class
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "NETWORK CLASS" Then
        NetCol = i
        'permit_status_1
        'dyea_1
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "DYEA 1" Then
        DY(1) = i
        'permit_status_1
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "PERMIT STATUS 1" Then
        PS(1) = i
        'dyea_2
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "DYEA 2" Then
        DY(2) = i
        'permit_status_2
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "PERMIT STATUS 2" Then
        PS(2) = i
        'dyea_3
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "DYEA 3" Then
        DY(3) = i
        'permit_status_3
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "PERMIT STATUS 3" Then
        PS(3) = i
        'dyea_4
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "DYEA 4" Then
        DY(4) = i
        'permit_status_4
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "PERMIT STATUS 4" Then
        PS(4) = i
        'dyea_5
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "DYEA 5" Then
        DY(5) = i
        'permit_status_5
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "PERMIT STATUS 5" Then
        PS(5) = i
        ElseIf CSheet.Cells(1, i) = "JOB STATUS" Then
        JS = i
    Else: End If
Next i
    
If DY(2) = 0 Then
    DYEAColCount = 1
Else: DYEAColCount = 5
End If

For x = 1 To DYEAColCount
    For y = 2 To cRow
        If CSheet.Cells(y, DY(x)) <> "" Then
            LCRow = LCSheet.Cells(LCSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row of Current
            LCSheet.Cells(LCRow + 1, 1) = PageName
            LCSheet.Cells(LCRow + 1, 2) = CSheet.Cells(y, ObIDCol) 'Object ID
            LCSheet.Cells(LCRow + 1, 3) = CSheet.Cells(y, NameCol)
            LCSheet.Cells(LCRow + 1, 4) = CSheet.Cells(y, NetCol)
            LCSheet.Cells(LCRow + 1, 5) = CSheet.Cells(y, DY(x))
            LCSheet.Cells(LCRow + 1, 6) = CSheet.Cells(y, PS(x))
            LCSheet.Cells(LCRow + 1, 7) = CSheet.Cells(y, JS)
        Else: End If
    Next y
    
    LCROw2 = LCSheet.Cells(LCSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Get new last row of Current
Next x
    
'Clean column data for next iteration
For n = 1 To 5
    DY(n) = 0
    PS(n) = 0
Next n

Next c

Debug.Print ("Copy Livemap Layer data into one set of columns: " & Format((Timer - StartTime2) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss"))
StartTime3 = Timer

'Remove rows with blank DYEAs
Application.StatusBar = "Remove blanks"
'LCSheet.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Debug.Print ("Remove blanks: " & Format((Timer - StartTime3) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss"))
StartTime2 = Timer

x = 3
LCROw2 = LCSheet.Cells(LCSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Get new last row of Current
LCSheet.Range(LCSheet.Cells(3, 8), LCSheet.Cells(LCROw2, 8)) = "=IF(ISBLANK(F" & x & "), 99, VLOOKUP(F" & x & ",'Permit Tracker BACKUP'!D:E, 2, 0)) + VLOOKUP(A" & x & ",'Permit Tracker BACKUP'!G:H, 2, 0)" 'not sure what it's supposed to do.
LCSheet.Range(LCSheet.Cells(3, 9), LCSheet.Cells(LCROw2, 9)) = "=IF(AND(F" & x & "<>"""",OR(A" & x & "=""CORE Permits"", A" & x & "=""NED Permits"", A" & x & "=""Anchor & Groundbed Permits"", A" & x & "=""Pole Placement Permits"")), IF(COUNTIFS(E$3:E" & x & ",E" & x & ",F$3:F" & x & ",F" & x & ")>1, """", 1), """")"
LCSheet.Range(LCSheet.Cells(3, 10), LCSheet.Cells(LCROw2, 10)) = "=IFERROR(INDEX('WORK ORDER REPORT'!B:B, MATCH(B3, 'WORK ORDER REPORT'!A:A, 0), 1) & """", """")" 


'Sort Status reverse alphabetical 
LCSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
LCSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("H2:H" & LCROw2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With LCSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

When running this code, I get a running Error number 9, and when I click debug, it points me to this line of code:

"Set CSheet = WB.Worksheets(PageName) 'Permit layer data sheets"

The code still works up until this point:

"'Remove rows with blank DYEAs
Application.StatusBar = "Remove blanks"
'LCSheet.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Debug.Print ("Remove blanks: " & Format((Timer - StartTime3) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss"))
StartTime2 = Timer"

meaning that the blank rows that have blank cells in the DYEA columns are removed, but then the rest of the code is NOT executed--the part that I had trouble with and that was solved by adding "X = 3" to the formulas, which is why I am running it as a separate sub routine. So the code is ultimately not executed towards the end.

Comment: code should not be as a photo.  Code should be text in the question itself and formated as a code block.

Comment: You're concatenating `x` into the formulas, but there is no `x` in the rest of the code.  Have you tried adding `x = 3` before creating the formulas?

Comment: ...the problem is pretty clear if you look at the formula bar in your screenshot.

Comment: @TimWilliams The problem wasn't "pretty clear" to me, but your solution worked all the same, so I appreciate that. I added the "X = 3"  before the formulas and it gets me the matches that I'm looking for. Thank you. Now the only thing is that I'm actually trying to add this code into a larger procedure or Sub Routine, and it won't read it, which is why I am running it as a separate routine. Any resources you'd recommend I check out in order to solve these smaller issues? Thanks again--and in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it won't read it" - what exactly happens when you try it?  You should be able to insert `ReferToCell` into your other routine to have it call this one.

Comment: @TimWilliams Alright, I edited my original post and added the entirety of the code I've been working on to get the results I am seeking to obtain. What I mean by "it won't' read it" is that the script is executed up until the point where I try to run the formulas you helped me with earlier and then it stops and gives me an error--this is why I am running that code chunk as a separate routine. It would be nice to get it all to run on the same routine though. I am not a developer and have limited experience in coding in anything besides R, so your help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: "an error" is not a really useful great description of what exactly happens when you try to run it.  If you're seeing errors, it's always useful to note (1) What is the text of the error (2) What line of code is highlighted when you click Debug

Comment: Note - If you do this `Dim A, B, C As Long` then only `C` is a Long, `A` and `B` are Variant.  In VBA you need to decalre the type for every variable: `Dim A As Long, B As Long, C As Long`

Comment: @TimWilliams the specific line that is pointed out when I get the error is on my description, it's the line that says 'Set CSheet = WB.Worksheets(PageName) 'Permit layer data sheets'

Comment: @TimWillaims, thanks for the clarification on the how to handle the declaration of each Variable, this helps a heap!! I will declare each variable type so that I don't run into issues down the line. Thanks Tim!

Comment: What's the value of `PageName` when it fails?  The error is telling you there's no sheet in `WB` with that name...

Comment: @TimWilliams it is giving me a `PageName = Error 2029` , but I had set `PageName = LCSheet.cells(1, C)` because I thought that would go through the names of sheets on my workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams I also declared PageName as a string--not sure if that's messing my script up somehow.

Comment: If `PageName = Error 2029` then there is an error on `LCSheet` where there should be a worksheet name.